# Adding Pagination to a 3rd party module (OT-MiniNewsModule)

Tags: php, joomla, pagination, components

i'm currently trying to modify a module that works almost perfectly for my requirements, but lacks pagination. I can't seem to grasp how i should add the pagination to it; most JPagination examples assume i have access to the query but in this module (which uses JFactory, JmoduleHelper & JModel) i don't see the query in order to add the limits and such.

## mod_otmininews.php

```
//No direct access!
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php';

$doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet(JURI::base().'/modules/mod_otmininews/css/layout.css');

$list = modOtMiniNewsHelper::getList($params);
$moduleclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_otmininews', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

## helper.php

```
//No direct access!
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models');

abstract class modOtMiniNewsHelper
{
public static function getList(&$params)
{
    // Get the dbo
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Get an instance of the generic articles model
    $model = JModel::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    // Set application parameters in model
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $appParams = $app->getParams();
    $model->setState('params', $appParams);

    // Set the filters based on the module params
    $model->setState('list.start', 0);
    $model->setState('list.limit', (int) $params->get('count', 3));
    $model->setState('filter.published', 1);

    // Access filter
    $access = !JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content')->get('show_noauth');
    $authorised = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));
    $model->setState('filter.access', $access);

    // Category filter
    $model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', array()));

    // User filter
    $userId = JFactory::getUser()->get('id');
    switch ($params->get('user_id'))
    {
        case 'by_me':
            $model->setState('filter.author_id', (int) $userId);
            break;
        case 'not_me':
            $model->setState('filter.author_id', $userId);
            $model->setState('filter.author_id.include', false);
            break;

        case '0':
            break;

        default:
            $model->setState('filter.author_id', (int) $params->get('user_id'));
            break;
    }

    // Filter by language
    $model->setState('filter.language',$app->getLanguageFilter());

    //  Featured switch
    switch ($params->get('show_featured'))
    {
        case '1':
            $model->setState('filter.featured', 'only');
            break;
        case '0':
            $model->setState('filter.featured', 'hide');
            break;
        default:
            $model->setState('filter.featured', 'show');
            break;
    }

    // Set ordering
    $order_map = array(
        'm_dsc' => 'a.modified DESC, a.created',
        'mc_dsc' => 'CASE WHEN (a.modified = '.$db->quote($db->getNullDate()).') THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END',
        'c_dsc' => 'a.created',
        'p_dsc' => 'a.publish_up',
        'h_dsc' =>  'a.hits',
    );
    $ordering = JArrayHelper::getValue($order_map, $params->get('ordering'), 'a.publish_up');
    $dir = 'DESC';

    $model->setState('list.ordering', $ordering);
    $model->setState('list.direction', $dir);

    $items = $model->getItems();

    foreach ($items as &$item) {
        $item->slug = $item->id.':'.$item->alias;
        $item->catslug = $item->catid.':'.$item->category_alias;

        if ($access || in_array($item->access, $authorised))
        {
            // We know that user has the privilege to view the article
            $item->link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catslug));
        }
        else {
            $item->link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_user&view=login');
        }
        //$item->title = htmlspecialchars( $item->title );
        $item->content= strip_tags(preg_replace('/<img([^>]+)>/i',"",$item->introtext));
        $item->content = substr($item->content, 0, $params->get('introtext_limit'));

        preg_match_all('/img.+src="([^"]+)"/i', $item->introtext, $matches);
        if(empty($matches[1][0])){
            $item->images="";
        }else{
            $item->images= $matches [1] [0];
        }

        //Show thumbnails
        if($params->get('showthumbnails')==1){
            if($item->images == ""){
                $item->thumbnail = '<img src="'.$params->get('directory_thumbdefault').'" width="'.$params->get('thumbwidth').'" height="'.$params->get('thumbheight').'" alt="'.$item->title.'" />';
            }else{
                $item->thumbnail = '<img src="' .$item->images.'" width="'.$params->get('thumbwidth').'" height="'.$params->get('thumbheight').'" alt="'.$item->title.'" />'  ;    //show images
            }
        }
        $item->created_date = $item->created; 
    }
    return $items;
}
}
```

All this code creates an array used by

## default.php

```
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>

<div class="ot_news">
    <div class="ot_news_i">


        <?php 
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>
        <div class="ot_items <?php echo ($params->get('count') == $count)?'last-item':''; ?>">
            <!-- Show thumbnails -->
            <?php if($params->get('showthumbnails') == 1){?>
                <div class="ot_thumbs"  style="width:<?php echo $params->get('thumbwidth')?>px; height:<?php echo $params->get('thumbheight')?>px;">
                     <?php if($params->get('enablelinkthumb') == 1) {?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->thumbnail ;?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php echo $item->thumbnail?>
                     <?php }?>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php echo ''; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- End -->
             <!-- Show Titles -->
            <div class="ot_articles">
                <?php if($params->get('showtitle') == 1) { ?>
                    <div class="ot_title">
                     <?php if($params->get('enablelinktitle') == 1) { ?>
                         <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
                    <?php }else{?>
                        <span class="title"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span>
                   <?php }?>
                   </div>
               <?php } ?>
                <!-- Show Created Date -->
               <?php
                   if ($params->get('show_date') == 1) { 
                    echo '<p class="createddate"><span class="ot_date">'; 
                    $date = $item->created_date;
                    echo JHTML::_('date', $date, $params->get( 'date_format' ));
                    echo '</span></p>'; 
                }
               ?>
               <!-- Show Content -->
                <div class="ot_content"><?php echo $item->content; ?></div>
                <!-- Show Readmore -->
                 <?php if($params->get('readmore') == 1) {?>
                <div class="ot_readmore"><a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="ot_readm"><?php echo JText::_('READMORE') ?></a></div>
                <?php }else {?>
                    <?php echo ''; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spaces"></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


    </div>
</div>
<div class="ot-mini-news"><?php echo JText::_('ABOUT_OT_MINI_NEWS'); ?></div>
```

that just uses a for each to show the items with their photos links and descriptions.

So as you can see i have seriously no clue where to add the Pagination code, and i suspect they even use some part of it for the display (i saw a getlist function in the helper.php file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JPagination_in_your_component This is a highly useful document for this - even though this is for a module and the wiki page is using it for a component.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 14, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons
$lim0   = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');
$db->setQuery('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS x, y, z FROM jos_content WHERE x',$lim0, $lim);
$rL=&$db->loadAssocList();
if (empty($rL)) {$jAp->enqueueMessage($db->getErrorMsg(),'error'); return;}     
else {
////Here the beauty starts
$db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();');  //no reloading the query! Just asking for total without limit
jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
$pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );
foreach($rL as $r) {
//your display code here
}
echo $pageNav->getListFooter(  ); //Displays a nice footer
```

You can see in their code that whilst they do use the db result, that the pagination doesn't 'depend' on the query. Only the results which come from it. So for the `$db->loadResult()` for example you can just use a php count forumla to see how many rows there are in the array being produced by the module. In your case counting the number of `$items`. 
The foreach command is still as you have it as well. With just the `foreach($rL as $r)` just corresponding to the existing `foreach($items as $item)`. So the fact you don't have the database query as you see - shouldn't actually be an issue!

So the code you want will be something like:

```
global $option; //If Joomla 1.5
global $mainframe; //If Joomla 2.5
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option') //If Joomla 2.5
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication(); //If Joomla 2.5
$lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 14, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons
$lim0   = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');
if (empty($items)) {
    $app->enqueueMessage($db->getErrorMsg(),'error');
    return;
} else {
    jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
    $pageNav = new JPagination( count($list), $lim0, $lim );
    foreach($list as $item) {
     //wrap in your code here that you had in the foreach already
}
echo $pageNav->getListFooter(  ); //Displays a nice footer
```

Make sure you remove one of the top two lines depending on whether you're using Joomla 1.5 or 2.5 but that *should* work.

Comment: So basically i should "wrap" the foreach code with the code you posted ? (sorry i cant up vote you not enough rep yet but ty so much!)

Comment: No worries! Have a look at updated answer. Put in the code relevant to you into the second code box. Hopefully should work once you've removed the code you don't need (commented as Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 on lines 1 & 2) and you've put your code into the foreach() statement!

Comment: I tried running the code but it gives out an error due to the "else {" without the if... i tried looking at the first code snippet and the 2nd one to see if i could fix it myself but im so lost its not funny.

Comment: oops. so i'm guessing you tried adding in the intial if statement ...
if (empty($rL)) {$jAp->enqueueMessage($db->getErrorMsg(),'error'); return;}     
before the else statement? What did that do?

Comment: This is the error i get from that:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserStateFromRequest() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\mascotas\modules\mod_otmininews\tmpl\default.php on line 26`

(line 26) `$lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 14, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons`

Comment: it usually means `$option` hasn't been defined. Which version of Joomla are you using? You have put in the correct definition of $option for you version>?

Comment: with that if statement - I just released your variable is being stored as `$items` and your JApplication variable is `$app` so the if statement I gave you yesterday should be `if (empty($items)) {$app->enqueueMessage($db->getErrorMsg(),'error'); return;}`. This won't affect the error your getting currently but is still important!

Comment: I used `global $option; //If Joomla 1.5`
although i just remembered my dev enviroment is 2.x, its the production env thats 1.x. 

after modifiying it i got a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\mascotas\modules\mod_otmininews\tmpl\default.php on line 27` error 

(line 27) `$lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 14, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons`

Comment: Just noticed for 2.5 you also need to declare `$mainframe` as $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication(); Sorry I keep missing these things! Does that still give you the same error?

Comment: yes, on the same line (which is now the `$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();` so i presume its a problem with the $option declaration 

`$option = JRequest::getCmd('option') //If Joomla 2.5
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        $lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 14, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons
        $lim0   = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int'); 
        $count = 0;`